# Add a field while serializing an object

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a case class

```
case class Foo(bar: Int, baz: String)
```

and I am trying to write a JSON serialization for it. But I have an additional requirement, to add one more field to the generated Json (say "greeting": "Hello")

I am trying something along these lines:

```
val writes = ((JsPath \ "bar").write[Int] and
   (JsPath \ "baz").write[String] and
   (JsPath \ "greeting").write[String])(unlift(Foo.unapply))
```

But, how should I pass the static "Hello" string to the above Writes?

And how can I use this `writes` to create a `Format` for my `Foo` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
val writes = Writes[Foo](f => {
  Json.obj(
    "bar" -> f.bar,
    "baz" -> f.baz,
    "greeting" -> "Hello")
})
```

Drawback is that you have to specify the members twice, but it's handy for special cases like this where you need additional control.

Answer (score 1):

In a one-off scenario, where you don't want to define yet another `Writes`, you could do this:

```
Json.toJson(foo).as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("greeting" -> "hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with another solution:

```
val writes = ((JsPath \ "bar").write[Int] and
  (JsPath \ "baz").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "greeting").write[String])((f: Foo) => (f.bar, f.baz, "Hello"))
```